# getline() function reading in whitespace before input is entered

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

Alright, I wrote a game of hangman. The game works great, except after the user finishes the game, and enters the char value of Y to play again.

I have traced the problem down to the getline() function at the start of my do-while loop. If I enter Y, then the do-while loop succesfully repeats, but the getline function seems to already think that there is input in cin, even though I don't enter anything.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() {





    string secretWord;
    string secretWordClean = "";
    string guessedLetters; //to be loaded with _ characters equal to length of secretWord
    string incorrectlyGuessedChars = "";
    char individualCharGuess;
    char playAgain;
    size_t countOfLetters = 0; //begine count at 0
    size_t guessesRemaining;
    int guessedUsed;


    begin_game://label which we can use to bring us back to the start of the do-while loop at any time

    do{//start of the game

    cout << "Please enter a secret word: ";
    getline(cin, secretWord); //y getline is cuaing the issue


     for(int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++){
            if (isalpha(secretWord[i])){ 
                    secretWordClean += secretWord[i];
            }
        }

     secretWord = secretWordClean; //assign all alpha secret word string back to original variable for better readability
     guessesRemaining = secretWord.length() * 2;

     for(int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++){
         guessedLetters += "_"; //fills guessedLetters with blanks equal to the length of the secretWord
     }




         cout << "Please guess a letter, you have " << guessesRemaining << " guesses remaining!" << endl;
         cin >> individualCharGuess;

         for(int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++){ //every complete iteration of this for loop = one single guess
                if(secretWord[i] == individualCharGuess){
                    guessedLetters[i] = individualCharGuess; //will replace the spaces with the correct character, if guessed
                    countOfLetters++; //if any letter is guessed correctly, this indicator will be inrimented above 0
                    continue;
                 }

                if(secretWord.find(individualCharGuess) == string::npos){
                    if(incorrectlyGuessedChars.find(individualCharGuess) == string::npos){
                    incorrectlyGuessedChars += individualCharGuess;
                    }
                }
         }

         if(secretWord.compare(guessedLetters) == 0){
             cout << "You win! The word was: " << secretWord << endl;
             guessedUsed = ((secretWord.length() * 2) - guessesRemaining) + 1 ;
             cout << "You used " << guessedUsed << " guesses." << endl; 
             cout << "Play again? Enter Y for Yes, or anything else to exit: ";
             cin >> playAgain;
             if(playAgain != 'Y'){
             break; //exit the loop if user guesses all the letters and doesn't want to play again
             }
             else {
                 goto begin_game;
             }
         }

         guessesRemaining--; //we decriment our total guesses remaining if the user does not win the game or run out of guesses

         if(countOfLetters > 0){
             cout << "You have correctly guessed a letter!" << endl;
             cout << "Here are the letters you have guessed correctly so far: ";
             cout << guessedLetters << endl;
             cout << "Here are the letters you have guessed incorrectly so far: ";
             cout << incorrectlyGuessedChars << endl;
             countOfLetters = 0; //reset the counter to prepare for next iteration of do-while loop
         }
         else if (guessesRemaining <= 0) {
             cout << "You have run out of guesses!" << endl;
             cout << "Here are the letters that you guessed correctly: ";
             cout << guessedLetters << endl;
             cout << "Here are the letters you guessed incorrectly: ";
             cout << incorrectlyGuessedChars << endl;
             cout << "The secret word was: " << secretWord << endl;
             cout << "Play again? Enter Y for Yes, or anything else to exit: ";
             cin >> playAgain;
             if(playAgain != 'Y'){
             break; //exit the loop if user guesses all the letters and doesn't want to play again
             }
             else goto begin_game;
         }
         else {
             cout << "You guessed wrong! Keep trying, " << guessesRemaining << " guesses to go!" << endl;
             cout << "Here are the letters you have guessed correctly so far: ";
             cout << guessedLetters << endl;
             cout << "Here are the letters you have guessed incorrectly so far: ";
             cout << incorrectlyGuessedChars << endl;
         }



     }while (secretWord.compare(guessedLetters) != 0 || guessesRemaining != 0); //use to repeat the request for a single char guess


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing formatted and unformatted I/O: reading a character will stop immediately after reading the character. Since after entering the character you entered a newline the newline still sticks in the stream, read for `getline()` to terminate the line. You should skip leading whitespace before using `std::getline()`, e.g.:

```
if (std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, s)) {
    ...
 }
```

Alternatively, you could use `ignore()` to ignore all characters up to and including the newline. Note that ignoring just one character won't work reliably as a sequence of spaces between the `'\n'`. To use `ignore()` you should use the proper magic number instead:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

BTW, you should also always verify that input was actually successful as you'd otherwise easily get incorrect behavior when it isn't.

Comment: On the other hand, `ignore` also skips over non-whitespace. I'd say that legitimate use cases for that should be rare, and it's almost always better to have pure line-based parsing in that case (and process each line separately, perhaps via a string stream).

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix token extraction using `>>` and line extraction using `getline`. The former doesn't remove newlines, so the next `getline` call after token extraction may end up reading the remaining bit of the previous line, which may be an empty string.

If you must mix the two kinds of input, use `std::cin >> std::ws` to gobble up stray whitespace (including the newline) before using `getline`.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I think the `1` isn't an ideal recommendation.

Comment: Didn't downvote but the reason `std::getline()` will incorrectly read after a formatted extraction is if the residual character is a delimiter (optionally specified by the third argument, `'\n'` by default). Also, `ignore(1, '\n')` only discards a single character (the second argument means nothing if the first argument is 0 or 1). Maybe you mean `std::cin >> std::ws` or `ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')`?

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I suppose... `1` is to prevent empty strings. If you needed more than `1`, you'd at least get a non-empty string otherwise.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Well, I'm mostly concerned with the situation where you erroneously get an empty string from `getline`. I think `std::ws` is the better option, though, I'll add that.

Comment: @0x499602D2: I'd also not go as far as calling `getline` "incorrect". It's simply that the interaction between line and token extraction is non-trivial.